# Atomic execution of multiple Firestore operations in Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing an app that involves operations in Firestore. I have a function that performs multiple operations such as updating counters and moving documents between collections. I want to ensure that all these operations are performed atomically, so if one operation fails, none of the other operations should be executed.

I know that transactions are batches can be used to achieve this, but as far as I know, they can only be used to perform multiple operations within the same funcion. Is it possible to achieve this atomic behaviour but with different functions?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
fun doOperations() {

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        try {
          
            val deferredList = listOf(

                async {
                    ClassA().updateDocument(docId, newData)                  
                },
                async {
                    ClassB().moveDocument(docId)         
                }
            )

            deferredList.awaitAll()

            // Continue

        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle error
        }

    }
}
```

```
class ClassA() {

    suspend fun updateDocument(docId: String, newData: String) { 

        val docRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("CollectionA").document(docId) 
        docRef.update("dataA", newData).await() 
    }
}
```

```
class ClassB() {

    suspend fun moveDocument(docId: String) {

        val initialCollection = Firebase.firestore.collection("CollectionB")
        val finalCollection = Firebase.firestore.collection("CollectionC")

        val documentSnapshot = initialCollection.document(docId).get().await()
    
        finalCollection.document(docId).set(documentSnapshot.data!!).await()
        initialCollection.document(docId).delete().await()
    }
}
```

If the the "updateDocument" fails (if the field "dataA" couldn't be updated in Firestore), the "moveDocument" should not be executed (the document should not be moved between Firestore collections), and viceversa.

Is it possible to achieve this ? Or the only thing to achieve this is to merge both functions and use batches/transactions?

I tried using batches and transactions, but I don't figure out how to do it with different functions.

Comment: Did you consider passing the transaction object between the functions that need access to it? That should allow you to share a single transaction across multiple functions.